# Vector with template gives error in Valgrind when printing the context

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am very confused why my code gives error when running the valgrind memory check:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./output
```

The code works perfectly when compile and run. But when running the valgrind tool it gives this message in the end.

> ERROR SUMMARY: 170 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)

It would be wonderful if someone could help me out.
Thank you   /Pete

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>

class Vector{
public:
    T* p;
    size_t size;
public:
Vector<T>(){
    cout << "The default constructor" << endl;
    this-> size = 10;    // initial size
    this->    p = new T[size];

}
~Vector<T>(){
    cout << "The destructor" << endl;
    delete [] p;
}

void print_values(){
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < this->size; ++i){
            std::cout << *(this->p+i) << " ";}
        std::cout << endl;
}   

};

int main(){
Vector <double> dvect;
//dvect.print_values();   // why gives error?
}
```

Comment: what type of `T` did you use to instantiate the template?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly then it is <double> I chose to use in main. But this is the first time I use template so I don't know much about it actually

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing your vector elements before printing them?  This change to your code fixed the valrgind errors for me:

```
--- foo.cpp.orig    2013-10-01 09:15:30.093127716 -0700
+++ foo.cpp 2013-10-01 09:15:34.293127683 -0700
@@ -16,7 +16,7 @@
 Vector<T>(){
     cout << "The default constructor" << endl;
     this-> size = 10;    // initial size
-    this->    p = new T[size];
+    this->    p = new T[size]();

 }
 ~Vector<T>(){
```

Note that I only got the valgrind errors when I uncommented your `dvect.print_values()` call.

Comment: I did try to give the values to the elements in the vector explicitly. It went without error too. But your technique is flawless. Thank you my savior.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

this is my result

```
==21382==
==21382== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21382==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21382==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 80 bytes allocated
==21382==
==21382== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==21382==
```

the error summary you got I think may from the headers which are not part of your code.

Comment: Did you uncomment the line that calls `print_values`? Doing that gives me the reported errors.